# How do I add a hover selector to a style object?

Tags: reactjs

I created a style object in react that I will pass through a style prop:

```js
const iconStyle = {
  color: "#464545",
  fontSize: "24px",
  margin: "20px",
  transitionProperty: "color",
  transitionDuration: "1s",
}
```

Any idea on how I could add a hover selector inside of it, because I've looked around and I still have no clue.

Comment: What sort of library are you using for css-in-js?

Answer (score 1):

probably this pseudo selector will help.

```
const iconStyle = {
        color: "#464545",
        fontSize: "24px",
        margin: "20px",
        transitionProperty: "color",
        transitionDuration: "1s",
        "&:hover": {
        background: "#efefef"
        },
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In React.js there is no such way hover. 
You can accomplish your goal with these two states.

```
onMouseEnter={() => this.setState({hover: true})}
onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({hover: false})}
```

And you can use "hover" state(for example) to specify styles like

```
style = this.state.hover ? style1 : style2
```

Hope this helps you to understand!